# getting value by tuple of dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple of dictionary of dictionary of list, I want to print value like

```
1
2
3
```

the given tuple is, how can I print that value. 
`k=('m',{'n':{'o':[1,2,3]}})`

Answer (score 3):

You can access the innermost list, like this `k[1]["n"]["o"]` and then we convert each element of it to a string, which we later join with `\n` and print it.

```
print "\n".join(map(str, k[1]["n"]["o"]))
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
 for i in  k[1]['n']['o']:
   print i
```